# Is there any way to write to a json file in angular rather than using fs module?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm stuck with fs module in angular 7 cause it is showing **can't find module fs** when I'm trying to write to json file. Please suggest me some alternatives for this.

Comment: Why not create simple JSON file and place it in assets folder as asset and use it?

Comment: Even if it is used as an assets, still it need some method to write the object into that json file. Right?

Comment: Are you trying to write a file to the users machine...?

Comment: Yes and I'm not using any database.

Comment: Oh like that, no you can't do using angular as of now

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. Angular is running in a browser, on a user pc or handheld or whatever.  It would be a security problem if your angular app would have access to the file system.

Google is planning this at the moment, but it's not standard.

What you can do:  You can read jsons files from server via http.get request or write json to the server via http.post requests.

angular will work together with every backend server : java-spring-boot or php or node.js, ...

In node.js you will find your fs.

P.S.: the npm and node_module in your angular app only exists during development. After compiling you get plain html, js and css.

Comment: But still we can use fs.writeFile() and be able to write to json file. How?